# As a whole vs. On the whole

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrases

Which phrase is okay in the following? I don't find example sentences in the dictionary clear enough to distinguish them.

> As a whole/On the whole, conditions in rural areas are getting better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You gave the following example: "_We manage the forest as a / on the whole_." But "to manage the forest" is not really understandable to me. Can I replace "forest" with "forestry"? I mean: can I consider "_We manage the forestry as a / on the whole_" instead? Thanks.

Comment: The word ***forestry*** normally means "The science and art of forming and cultivating forests, management of growing timber" (***forest*** is the normal term for "An extensive tract of land covered with trees"). So no - I *wouldn't* endorse *managing the forestry*. But we can think of even one forest as a large and complex entity, so it can be ***managed as a whole*** (i.e. - managed ***as a single unit***, not just as a disparate bunch of trees that happen to be growing next to reach other). ***on the whole*** is a completely unrelated idiom that's appropriate to OP's example, not mine.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but if you're still interested, I found the explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mM20_PTMy1s&ab_channel=iswearenglish) easy to grasp and quite illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

"On the whole" has the implication that most things are getting better, but there definitely are some noticeable things that are worse. But if you add everything up the sum is positive. Also, I think I see "On the whole" at the beginning of a sentence more often. It emphasizes the fact that we're talking about the average.

I think "As a whole" is not used as often this way. But if we look at [mirriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20a%20whole) they do have an example that basically fits your usage:

> The company as a whole is doing well.

When I read this, I think it is telling me that the company is doing well overall, and it doesn't imply to me that there are necessarily significant negative aspects to the company.

Comment: Does "On the whole, the company is doing well" imply there are still negative aspects?

Comment: I think so. Some, possibly small, negative aspects.

Comment: Of "The company as a whole is doing well," you said, " Things aren't perfect but we're still getting our bonuses." So "The company as a whole is doing well" also suggests there are still negative aspects?

Comment: Yes, I think that addition was confusing, sorry. I'll remove it. I think "as a whole" does leave open a possibility that the range of things is positive to neutral. They are pretty similar!

Comment: I think the only reason for including _as a whole_ would be that one or more sections of the company are not doing so well.

Comment: @KateBunting: I think *that* distinction is more likely to apply with ***on** the whole*. The far less likely ***As a whole,** the company is doing well* wouldn't necessarily imply that *any* parts aren't doing well - simply that the company wouldn't (or ***didn't***) do so well if (or ***when***) it wasn't "fully integrated".